# floor function for the following function.

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am looking to calculate the floor function for the following function. Suppose $n\ge 5$ and n is odd. also let $i\geq\frac{n+1}{2}$, what will be the floor function for the following equation.

$$\bigg\lfloor\frac{n^2+n-2i}{2n}\bigg\rfloor$$

Comment: What do you mean by the floor function for a function?

Comment: It simplifies to $${n+1\over2}+\left[-{i\over n}\right]$$

Comment: @GerryMyerson. I got you. but i have confusion about the term $$[\frac{-i}{n}].$$you mean it will be floor for some values of $i$ and will be ceilling for some value of $i$. Is this will be $\lfloor\frac{-i}{n}\rfloor$??

Comment: $[x]$ is the notation I use for the floor function.